# How to have 2 synchronised nested loops in React?

Tags: reactjs

I currently have this loop in React that goes trough a list of elements. I now want to have another list that would only loop once for each outer loop. Not sure if this is clear enough but let's say that my first list is ["a","b","c"] and my second list is ["1","2","3"]. I want the result to be 1a, 2b, 3c. I know how this can be done with an ordinary for loop but I've no idea on how to accomplish this in React.

```
  const Packages = ({ props }) => {
  const { title, packages } = props;
  return (
    <div className="productsContainer">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <Container fluid={true}>
        <Row noGutters={true}>
          {packages.map((el, index) => {
            return (
              <Col key={index} md={4} xs={12}>
                <div className="package" style={{ backgroundColor: el.bgColor }}>
                  <img alt="package" src={el.image} className="svg" />

                  <div className="packageInfo" style={{ backgroundColor: el.bgColor }}>
                    {document.getElm}
                    <div className="packageName">
                      <a href="/packages">
                        <button>{el.title}</button>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <Row>
                      {el.list.map((element, index) => {
                        return (
                          <Col md={6} key={index} className="textInfo" style={{ color: el.textColor }}>
                            <p>{el.icons} {element}</p>
                          </Col>
                        );
                      })}
                    </Row>
                  </div>
                  <div className="packageMore">
                    <a href="/packages">{el.link}</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Col>
            );
          })}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Packages;

     packages: {
        title: "Title",
        packages: [
          {
            title: "Start",
            list: ["List1", "List2"],
            icons: ["<i className=\"fas fa-briefcase\"></i>", "<i className=&#34;fas fa-briefcase&#34;></i>"],
            link: "Link",
            bgColor: "white",
            textColor: "black",
            image: START,
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map your icons with the list using the index of the array.

```
{
  el.list.map((element, index) => {
    return (
      <Col
        md={6}
        key={index}
        className="textInfo"
        style={{ color: el.textColor }}
      >
        <p>
          <i className={el.icons[index]} />
          {secondList[index]}
        </p>
      </Col>
    );
  });
}

const packages = {
  title: "Title",
  packages: [
    {
      title: "Start",
      list: ["List1", "List2"],
      icons: ["fas fa-briefcase", "fas fa-briefcase"],
      link: "Link",
      bgColor: "white",
      textColor: "black",
      image: START
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: I've just done that and I'm getting a "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" error.

Comment: Did you define `secondList`?

Comment: Yes, it works if I remove [index] but than it's just a regular loop.

Comment: Where is your second array?

Comment: The second array is icons and the first is list. I want to show an icon first and then List1.

Comment: I'm still getting a " Cannot read property '0' of undefined" error.

Comment: Check it once again, will you?

Comment: I've changed it with el and element and both give the same error.

Comment: This does work. The mistake was on my end. Sorry and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

lodash library has zip method for this

```
_.zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]).map(([v1, v2]) => {
  console.log(v1 + '-' + v2)
}) 

// result
// a-1
// b-2
// c-3
```

Comment: You don't need a library to perform this, mate. Using a library is an overkill.

Comment: @PrateekThapa, lodash provides a lot of methods that helps to develop beautifully and fastly, so why not? This way is more readable than dealing with indexes

Comment: `listA.map((a, index) => a + listB[index])` I don't think doing something as simple as this needs a library.